# How to preserve reference by property

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm setting up an automapper profile to map Revit element (from their api) to some custom element.
Their API got circular references (1 element => n parameters, 1 parameter => 1 element) I call the PreserveReference() methods. But it doesn't seem to work because I have a StackOverflowException.
So, I'm wondering how the PreserveReference works? Can I specify a property to check equality instead of using references?

```
public class Element
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Element element && Id == element.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // ReSharper disable once NonReadonlyMemberInGetHashCode
        return Id;
    }
}

public class Parameter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Definition Definition { get; set; }

    public Element Element { get; set; }
}


profile.CreateMap<Element, Models.Element>()
            .ForMember(element => element.Id, expression => expression.MapFrom(element => element.Id.IntegerValue))
            .IncludeAllDerived()
            .PreserveReferences();

profile.CreateMap<Parameter, Models.Parameter>()
            .ForMember(parameter => parameter.Id, expression => expression.MapFrom(parameter => parameter.Id.IntegerValue))
            .IncludeAllDerived()
            .PreserveReferences();
```

Comment: Starting from 6.1.0 PreserveReferences is set automatically at config time, so there is no need to set it. Upgrade to the latest. If that doesn't work, make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Even if I set it or not, it still doesn't work. Revit API is made so that I need to tell AutoMapper to preserve reference based on the Id property : http://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/671c33f6-169b-17ca-583b-42f9df50ace5.htm

Comment: No, the idea is that you won't get SO. Whatever that API wants, that's different. AM has no such thing. AM.Collections does smth similar, so you might want to try that.

Comment: I'm still getting SO. This is rather logic because, with the Revit API, two element with equal Id can be not equals.

Comment: If you get SO while mapping, give me a repro and I'll take a look.

Comment: @RomainDAROCHA Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others. Mark the line where the exception is thrown and add the full exception message to the question. You might want to truncate the stack trace of that exception message since it is a StackOverflowException.

Comment: I could. But you would need to have Revit installed to be able to test it.

Comment: OK, so the SO is not with the mapping then.

Comment: No, the mapping is fine, Automapper is fine. I just need a way to tell your InstanceCache in the ResolutionContext that he should use the Id property of the revit element as a key and not the element itself.

Comment: Maybe you want to try a PR :) Or see if AM.Collections can help.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to get what I want. I had to get access to a private property like that :

```
public static T GetSource<T>(this ContextCacheKey contextCacheKey)
    {
        var source = (T)typeof(ContextCacheKey).GetField("_source", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance)?.GetValue(contextCacheKey);

        return source;
    }

    public class ElementConverter : IValueConverter<Element, Models.Element>
    {
        public Models.Element Convert(Element sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var a = (Models.Element)context.InstanceCache.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key.GetSource<Element>().Id.Equals(sourceMember.Id)).Value ?? context.Mapper.Map<Models.Element>(sourceMember);

            return a;
        }
    }
```

A simple solution would be so have Source and DestinationType public in the ContextCacheKey struc :

```
public struct ContextCacheKey : IEquatable<ContextCacheKey>
{
    public static bool operator ==(ContextCacheKey left, ContextCacheKey right) => left.Equals(right);
    public static bool operator !=(ContextCacheKey left, ContextCacheKey right) => !left.Equals(right);

    public readonly object _source;
    public readonly Type _destinationType;

    public ContextCacheKey(object source, Type destinationType)
    {
        _source = source;
        _destinationType = destinationType;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => HashCodeCombiner.Combine(_source, _destinationType);

    public bool Equals(ContextCacheKey other) =>
        _source == other._source && _destinationType == other._destinationType;

    public override bool Equals(object other) => 
        other is ContextCacheKey && Equals((ContextCacheKey)other);
}
```

Comment: That's just silly :) Why not have your own dictionary and use that however you want?

Comment: Seems like a bit more complicated to have my own dictionnaries, for each types, to store everything during a map and clear once the map is done. Right now, I don't even know how I could do that :/

Comment: You have Context.Items and you can store there whatever.

Comment: I tried an IValueConverter with a custom dictionary inside as a cache. But if the dictionary is empty or if the element has not been mapped yet, I have to call Context.Mapper.Map<T>(sourceMember). Which will call soon or later, because of circular references, the ValueConverter, that will check the dictionary, which is still empty, so it'll call again the Map function, etc... Then SO again.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). You can see how AM does it and try to emulate that.